# Need a string value on an Attribute on my HDF5 File

Tags: c#, string, encoding, attributes, hdf5

i am trying to add some attributes on my datasets and it is working fine, but i have one problem when writing the value of the attributes, i need them to be a string, not a INT nor float or whatever, every tutorial i find on the internet uses a int value for those attributes..
I've tried a lot of different things and none of them works well and the code is becoming very ugly, this is my code:

```
    foreach (BasicVariable bv in pf.basicVariableList.bvList)
    {               
        H5DataSetId dataSetId = H5D.create(bvGroupId, bv.bvTag, typeId, spaceId);
        bv.atribList.Add(new Atribbs("Eng. Unit", "Temperatura"));
        bv.atribList.Add(new Atribbs("Atrib2", "Teste"));
        foreach(Atribbs a in bv.atribList )
        {


            H5DataTypeId auxDT = H5T.copy(H5T.H5Type.C_S1);
            H5T.setSize(auxDT, H5T.getSize(H5T.H5Type.C_S1));
            const int auxData = 2;
            long[] auxDim = new long[1];
            auxDim[0] = 1;
            H5DataSpaceId auxDS = H5S.create_simple(1, auxDim);


            var attr_id = H5A.create(dataSetId, a.attName, auxDT, auxDS);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a.valueStr);
            var atrData = new string[] { Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes)};
            H5A.write<string>(attr_id, auxDT, new H5Array<string>(atrData));

            H5A.close(attr_id);
        }
        H5D.close(dataSetId);
    }
    H5F.close(fileId);
```

The attributes i've created are "Eng. Unit" and "Atrib2" and that is working fine, the problem is thet the "Eng. Unit" should have the "Temperatura" value and "Atrib2" should have "Teste" as it's value, this is what i get on the hdfl viewer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFes8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45wxX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to have a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com/), which greatly simplifies how HDF5 files are handled. Here goes a solution using HDFql in C# (assume that the HDF5 file is named `test.h5` and the dataset is named `dset`):

```
HDFql.Execute("USE FILE test.h5");   // use (i.e. open) HDF5 file "test.h5"

HDFql.Execute("CREATE ATTRIBUTE \"dset/Eng. Unit\" AS VARCHAR VALUES(Temperatura)");   // create attribute "Eng. Unit" in dataset "dset" with an initial value of "Temperatura"

HDFql.Execute("CREATE ATTRIBUTE dset/Atrib2 AS VARCHAR VALUES(Teste)");   // create attribute "Atrib2" in dataset "dset" with an initial value of "Teste"
```

Comment: Oh gosh... This is perfect

Comment: I just need help adding the HDFql to my project... Can you help me? i downloaded the .zip file

Comment: Please take a look at section 3.5. of the reference manual (http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) as it explains how to use/setup HDFql in C#.

Comment: Thanks! Is working! Another thing... I want to store objects on the dataset, it has 3 attributes, DateTime, Int64 and String, how can i create a dataset with those three columns data types?